# Can i add CSS style to a echo script alert message?

Tags: php, css, styles

I want to add some styling to a pop-up alert echo script that i have in a .php file.

```
    if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email))
{
    echo "<script>
        alert('All values are required.');
        window.location.href='index.html#contact';
        </script>";
    exit;
}
```

The above is what i currently have, and i wish to style this part:

```
echo "<script>
    alert('All values are required.');
    window.location.href='index.html#contact';
    </script>";
exit;
```

How would i do this? I tried adding an id to the script, like this:

```
echo "<script id='alert'>
    alert('All values are required.');
    window.location.href='index.html#contact';
    </script>";
exit;
```

But that didn't seem to work - also, should i link my css file inside my .php file?

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: That's a system alert. It's not possible to style.

Comment: Ah, dang it. Do you have an alternative to a system alert?

Comment: Yes, you can use `bootbox` or similar plugins... `:)`